# Recognize separate delimiters Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I a trying to read from a file using scanner that uses two different delimiters and places them into a 2D array. What I want is while 1 delimiter is being read, place the strings into the array along one dimension. When the second delimeter is read, increment the array by 1 in other dimension and start placing values in the next index of the second dimension.I'd like something like this:

```
 i = 0;
 k = 0;
 int[][] array;
 while(scanner.hasNext()){
    if(delim1){
        array[i][k] = scanner.next();
        i++;
     }
    else if (delim2){
         i = 0;
         k++;
         array[i][k] = scanner.next();
     }
 }
```

I really just need to know how to differentiate between which delimiter is being read

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is formatted like

0,3,3,6-5,4,6,2-5,4,3,6

Try this, which reads one character on each iteration of the loop.

```
String delim1 = ",";
String delim2 = "-";
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
  String s = scanner.next();
  if (s.equals(delim1)) {
    i++;
    continue;
  } else if (s.equals(delim2)) {
    i = 0;
    k++;
    continue;
  }
  array[i][k] = Integer.parseInt(s); 
}
```